# Can I extend the Logger class without changing logged module name / function name / line number?

Tags: python, logging

I want to avoid writing code like `logger.debug(msg, extra=self.extra)`. So far I've tried to do this in two ways (extending Logger and decorators), but neither succeeded.

If I extend the Logger  class and implement methods like debug as follows:

```
def debug(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
    self._update_kwargs(**kwargs)
    super(ExtendedLogger, self).debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

The module / function name / line number that are logged are not the call sites of ExtendedLogger.debug, but the call `super(ExtendedLogger, self).debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)`; ie they're always the same values. I have the same issue if I try to implement something similar with decorators.

I understand this is due to the call to `findCaller` in `_log` in this file: [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/logging/**init**.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py) (R.1284). Is it possible to log this extra data without essentially copy-pasting the implementation of Logger and tweaking it slightly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the exact purpose for which [`LoggerAdapter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#loggeradapter-objects) exists:

> `LoggerAdapter` instances are used to conveniently pass contextual information into logging calls.

You might not even need to subclass anything, just use `LoggerAdapter` directly:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra={'extra_key': 'extra_value'})
```

If you want to provide the extra values dynamically, you can easily just subclass `LoggerAdapter` and override its `process` method to add extra values to all logging methods.

This avoids needing to override all the level-oriented logging methods (`debug`, `info`, `warning`, etc.) and also nicely side-steps the `findCaller` issue at the same time.